# How do I change web hosts when my domain name is registered through my web hosting company?

Tags: web-hosting, domain-registration, mx-record

I want to change my web hosting company.  However they are also the people who have administered and annually renewed my domain name.  I'm concerned about making the change because my original hosts might not feel motivated to help make the change as smooth as possible.  Worst case they could even be vindictive and screw up my MX record (currently pointing to google apps email), jeopardizing the reliability of my primary email address.  In fact, that's about my only concern - my website could be down for a month and it would be OK - I just want the MX record to always be pointing to google.

One other point:  While I'm paying my web host for domain name renewal, WhoIs shows the registrar as Tucows.  I'd be happy to work with Tucows directly if that somehow helps...

Finally, even though I'm able to say "MX record" (and was eventually able to correctly modify it a few years ago), I barely understand any of this.  So I'd appreciate as simple and jargon-free an answer as you can bear to type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new host does domain registration they can transfer the domain (just ask, they'll know exactly what you're talking about). If not, you'll have to find a domain registrar who will hold it separately (GoDaddy, NetSol, and plenty of others). The process is not that complicated (normally) and is usually very smooth).

Your domain name is your property; they are simply custodians of it. If they purposely and maliciously screw with you they're technically hacking (in the legal sense) and there's legal avenues to stop them and get remedies. Honestly though, I've never seen it come to this. Most of the time you're a pain in their butt too and they just want to be rid of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend transferring the domain out to another registrar.  GoDaddy is cheap and offers toll-free phone support and can help you with all of the technical details in regards to transferring the domain over to them.  You will want to replicate your current DNS records there as well and use GoDaddy's DNS hosting (they can help you with this as well).

Once the domain has been transferred, you will have full control over it and can make the hosting change as needed.  I specifically mention GoDaddy here because of their generally excellent customer service and ability to walk non-technical people through the process.  You can use any registrar, but for someone non-technical you will want to choose a company with free phone support.